# Django set manual arithmetic formula for a field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to set manual arithmetic formula of a field in a model, the formula changes from object to object of the model and is set by some user and sets it depending on the foreign model name.

**For example:**

```
model B:
name =char

model A:  
field 1 = int  
field 2 = int 
field 3 = foreign(model B)
field 4 = set formula
```

In object 1 of model A, Admin sets field4 = field1 + field2 if field 3 = "x" from admin portal

In object 2 of model A, Admin sets field4 = field1 * field2 if
field 3 = "y" from admin portal

Is this possible in Django?

Actually, I am trying to convert my excel sheet data into Django application, in my excel sheet for a given tab (here model A) I will have some fixed columns (here model B) but there is a column for which I will set the arithmetic formula of columns based on the tab name.
Now in my Django application based on the name of model A, I need to be able to set a formula for model B.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Does Django provide builtin functions to achieve this? No.

Can you customize Django achieve this? Yes.

```
import operator
operator_map = {"+": operator.add, "-":operator.sub...}
class ModelB:
    _operator <- while will store a raw operator
    @property
    def operator(self):
        return operator_map[self._operator]
```

If the operator is going to be dynamic. [Store the operator function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) as another column and in your property

```
class Model
    @property
    def field4(self):
        return self.field3.operator(self.field1, self.field2)
```

Comment: Hey, I edited my question a bit . can you answer it now, please?

Comment: I modified the answer accordingly