# Django Set a Formula for field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-models

I want to set manual arithmetic formula of a field in a model, the formula changes from object to object of the model and is set by some superuser and sets it depending on the foreign model name.

```
class Strategy(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class Line(models.Model):
 strategy = models.ForeignKey(Strategy,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 startvalue = models.FloatField(default=0)
 endvalue = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
 target = models.FloatField(default=0)
 alpha = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

So, Here there will be many strategies, And for each strategy I want superuser to map an arithmetic formula for alpha in terms of startvalue, endvalue, target, there will be many strategies and hence many formulae for alpha

for example, if a strategy is

> s1 then alpha = 100*(startvalue+endvalue*target)
>
> s2 then alpha = startvalue-endvalue*target

Like this, the superuser needs to set the formula of alpha for a strategy through **GUI** so that all Lines with that strategy have that formula for alpha.

How to implement this? Please help me, I'm stuck here for more than two days.

Comment: are every formula user defined ?

Comment: yes, he writes an arithmetic formula which includes some integers,+,-,*./. and those variables

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom form for the ModelAdmin:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form

Then override the `clean` method in the form to inspect the strategy field and set alpha:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: That's ok, but how to add a formula field in a form, can you help me completely, please

Comment: Can you be more specific? If the user is creating a new Line, then they have to pick a strategy, when you override the clean method, then you can see what strategy they selected and then set alpha to whatever you want.

Comment: The user needs to set a arithmetic formula, he can set any formula for alpha, which is going to to be fixed for a strategy

Comment: Allowing users to create formulas has the potential to be disastrous. How many variations formulas for start_value, end_value, target are you expecting? If the client needs a new formula I suggest you do this programmatically, and bill them a modest fee. There is no such thing, as far as I can tell as a formula field. A formula could be stored as a string potentially, and then you could use eval. That would not be considered safe nor best practise.

Comment: yes, he writes an arithmetic formula which includes some integers,+,-,*./. and those variables(start value,end value, target) for each strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer at [Django set manual arithmetic formula for a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980831/django-set-manual-arithmetic-formula-for-a-field/50980873#50980873)

You would need to create a meta of the formula and have properties to execute them during runtime.

```
import operator
operator_map = {"+": operator.add, "-":operator.sub...}
class ModelB:
    _operator <- while will store a raw operator
    @property
    def operator(self):
        return operator_map[self._operator]
```

Comment: Store the operator function as another column and in your property, what do you mean by that? can you please elaborate it?

Comment: Basically, you store operators as string like "+", "-" etc., or you can store it as "add", "sub"(functions in opertor module). 

During runtime, you use something like 


`getattr(operator, 'add')(Field1, Field2)`